# Laravel Auth login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using laravel 5.1

```
Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('ID');
    $table->string('usr_UserName');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->integer('usr_PeopleID')
        ->length(10)
        ->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->integer('usr_GroupID')
        ->unsigned()
        ->length(10);
    $table->integer('usr_DeletedID')
        ->unsigned()
        ->length(10);
    $table->integer('usr_UpdatedID')
        ->unsigned()
        ->length(10)
        ->nullable();
    $table->integer('usr_CreatedID')
        ->unsigned()
        ->length(10)
        ->nullable();
```

This is my migration code for users table and this is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

I'm trying to login and everything is ok but it redirects to login page again!
There is no error but I can't login

Comment: Auth should be in middleware...

Comment: stupid question but have you added the user data to the DB for it to log in?

Comment: Check your AuthController `protected $redirectTo = 'your_route';`. Maybe it is set to `login` again.

Comment: yes i added data in DB

Comment: i set that to my route thats not the problem